Paul Says He Is Of "The Stock Of Israel, Of The Tribe Of Benjamin, An Hebrew Of The Hebrews", Why Does He Also Call Himself A "Jew"G2453?
Paul Says He Is Of "The Stock Of Israel, Of The Tribe Of Benjamin, An Hebrew Of The Hebrews", Why Does He Also Call Himself A "Jew"/G2453?
Philippians 3:5 Circumcised the eighth day, of “”the stock of Israel, of the tribe of Benjamin, an Hebrew of the Hebrews””; as touching the law, a Pharisee;
Rom 11:1“I say then, Hath God cast away his people? God forbid. For I also am an Israelite, of the seed of Abraham, of the tribe of ""Benjamin""
Acts 21:39 But Paul said, I am a man which am a Jew/G2453 of Tarsus, a city in Cilicia, a citizen of no mean city: and, I beseech thee, suffer me to speak unto the people. 40And when he had given him licence, Paul stood on the stairs, and beckoned with the hand unto the people. And when there was made a great silence, he spake unto them in the Hebrew tongue, saying
I am looking for a specific verse, you should know this..

We should know that you are looking for a specific verse?  May I ask if you genuinely don't know what this specific verse is?

You've asked three questions now which are essentially the same: what does "Jew" mean? Please stop, it is not helpful to ask minor variations of the same question.

Ezekiel 37:21-22
New American Bible (Revised Edition)

21 Say to them: Thus says the Lord God: I will soon take the Israelites from among the nations to which they have gone and gather them from all around to bring them back to their land. 22 I will make them one nation in the land, upon the mountains of Israel, and there shall be one king for them all. They shall never again be two nations, never again be divided into two kingdoms.

Ezekiel 37:16-17

16 As for you, son of man, take one stick and write on it, “Judah and those Israelites associated with it.” Then take another stick and write on it: “Joseph, Ephraim’s stick, and the whole house of Israel associated with it.” 17 Join the two sticks together so they become one stick in your hand

Chuck Missler writes in an article The Ten Lost Tribe Myth

The same is true in the New Testament. Our Lord is said to have offered Himself to the nation, "the lost sheep of the house of Israel" (Matthew 10:5-6; 15:24). Tribes other than Judah are mentioned specifically in the New Testament as being represented in the land.15
Anna knew her tribal identity was of the tribe of Asher (Luke 2:36). Paul knew he was of the tribe of Benjamin, a "Jew" and an "Israelite" (Romans 11:1). The New Testament speaks of "Israel" 75 times and uses the word "Jew" 174 times.16
At the Feast of Pentecost Peter cries, "Ye men of Judea" (Acts 2:14), "ye men of Israel..." (Acts 2:22), and "All the house of Israel" (Acts 2:36)
Anti-Semitism
Accompanying some of the legends of the so-called "Ten Lost Tribes" are aspersions on the present State of Israel and the people being regathered in the Land. These various theories such as "British Israelism" are by their nature anti-Semitic because they deny the Jewish people their proper place in the plan of God. Let's remember that Genesis 12:3 has never been repealed!


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
